# Find limit of sum using Riemann integral

Tags: limits, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I need to find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{1+n*2^{\frac{k}{n}}}$$ using Riemann integral.

I think I might substitute $x$ for $2^{\frac{k}{n}}$and integrate from $1$ to $2$ but I'm not sure where to go from that, namely how to factor out $(x_{i+1}-x_i)$. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

---

I tried doing this:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{1+n*2^{\frac{k}{n}}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+2^{\frac{k}{n}}} = \int_0^1{\frac{1}{2^x}dx} = \frac{1}{2\ln{2}}$$

It looks like a correct answer according to WolframAlpha but I'm not sure how to safely remove that $\frac{1}{n}$ from denominator. I was told that series expansions can help with that but I have troubles applying them here.

Comment: Just for your curioisity, $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{1+n \,a^{\frac{k}{n}}}$ has a closed form in terms of the digamma function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try to show that the error we have if we simply remove the $1/n$ in the denominator is small. We have
$$
\Bigl|\frac{1}{1+n2^{k/n}}-\frac{1}{n2^{k/n}}\Bigr|=\frac{1}{(1+n2^{k/n})n2^{k/n}}\leq\frac{1}{n^2 (2^{2/n})^k}\leq\frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Now, by the triangle inequality, we find that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\biggl|\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{1+n2^{k/n}}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n2^{k/n}}\Bigr| &\leq
\sum_{k=0}^n\Bigl|\frac{1}{1+n2^{k/n}}-\frac{1}{n2^{k/n}}\Bigr|\\
&\leq\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^n1=\frac{n+1}{n^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
This error tends to $0$ as $n\to+\infty$. Thus
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{1+n2^{k/n}}
=
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n2^{k/n}}
=
\int_0^1\frac{1}{2^x}\,dx=\frac{1}{2\ln 2}.
$$